# Convert from ASCII code to string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, ascii

If I have a string in matlab, I can convert it to a vector of ASCII codes using `double`:

```
>> my_string = 'asd';
>> double(my_string)

ans =

    97   115   100
```

How can I go back the other way? i.e., if I have an ASCII code in a MATLAB vector, how can I create the corresponding string?

e.g

```
ascii_codes = [97 115 100];
```

should be converted to...

```
my_string = 'asd'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about `char` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/char.html))? Eg `char(ascii_codes)`?

Answer (score 1):

A great alternative to the [char](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) function, in my opinion, is the [native2unicode](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/native2unicode.html) function. It handles many different encoding schemes, allowing you to explicitly specifying the one to be used through its second input argument:

> unicodestr = native2unicode(bytes, encoding) converts bytes to a
>   Unicode representation with the assumption that bytes is in the
>   character encoding scheme specified by encoding. The input argument
>   encoding must have no characters ('') or it must be a name or alias
>   for an encoding scheme. Some examples are 'UTF-8', 'latin1',
>   'US-ASCII', and 'Shift_JIS'. If encoding is unspecified or has no
>   characters (''), the default encoding scheme is used. encoding can be
>   a character vector or a string scalar.

Usage example:

```
>> ascii_codes = [97 115 100];
>> my_string = native2unicode(ascii_codes,'ASCII')

my_string =

    'asd'
```