# Displaying a string in a matrix in matlab returns ascii

Tags: matlab, ascii

I am running the following loop in matlab:

> for k=1:n
>       s(k,:) = [k,'l']
>   end

Instead of getting 'l', I have 108 which corresponds to its ascii.

I found several examples on how to convert a number to its ascii value. For the other way, I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192887/convert-from-ascii-code-to-string-in-matlab) that 'char' could do the trick. However, replacing 'l' by char(108) still returns me 108 instead of char.

I noticed that

> for k=1:n
>       s(k,:) = char(108)
>   end

would display me 'l'. Why is it not the case in a matrix, and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab uses dynamic typing in which it infers the type of a variable based on what you assign to it.  For example try this:

```
x = [72 69 76 76 79 6]
y = [72 69 76 'L' 79 6]
```

Notice that the `x` becomes an array of doubles, while `y` becomes an array of chars.  Now if you try to set

```
x(2) = 'A'
```

the array `x` will maintain its type. But if you set

```
x = [72 'A' 76 76 79 6]
```

then  `x` will change its type to an array of chars. If you want to force an array to be a char array, then you can simply call `char()` on the entire array.

```
x = char([72 69 76 76 79 6])
```

In your case, you could just call

```
s = char(s)
```

after running through your loop.  This will recast the array as chars instead of doubles.

Also, notice that you cannot mix types in your matrix.  It looks like you are trying to put numbers in the first column and letters in the second. This is technically not allowed.  However, as long as you cast the value in the second column back to a char when access it, you shouldn't have a problem.  For example,

```
for k=1:n
    s(k,:) = [k,'l'];
end

first_number = s(1,1);
first_letter = char(1,2);
```

Will essentially let you store numbers in one column and letters in the other. You just have to make sure to cast the letter to a char whenever you access it from the matrix.

You could also consider using cells.  For example

```
n = 26;
s = cell(n,2);
for k=1:n
    s{k,1} = k;
    s{k,2} = 'l';
end

display(s)
```

If you don't like the way that Matlab displays the cell array, you can still extract pieces of the array using the following notation

```
% Pull out individual elements
first_number = s{1,1}
first_letter = s{1,2}

% Pull out the columns as matrices
numbers_as_matrix = cell2mat(s(:,1));
letters_as_matrix = cell2mat(s(:,2));
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to mix numbers and strings because I want to write these in a text file. I use dlmwriter. However, your method allows me to extract the content of the matrix correctly, but not to put it in  a matrix I could later write...

Comment: Unless you convert the number to a string by using `num2str()`  This will cause problems though if your numbers get higher than 9, since the ascii representation of 10 requires a string of width two.

Comment: You might want to look into storing the values in cell arrays (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) since they allow mixed types.

Comment: using num2str for k would work... unfortunately, k cold be 1, 2, 3 etc digits and therefore, I cannot preassign the size of s. I tried to look at the cells, but can't get my code working with them yet.

Comment: I had some problems using the cells (they dont' work with dlmwriter. It was suggested to use xlswriter but it generates a csv file). I finally managed to write what I wanted using fprintf http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf98f7
Thankyou again for your help